# Lasso implementation in Python

Tags: python, regularization, parameter-estimation

I am working on this course on Machine Learning 2012 from UBC (CPSC 340). I am stuck on a Homework code problem which shows the following `RuntimeError` in `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add, C = np.diag(np.dot(X.T, (ytile.T - protile.T + third.T)))`

Can anyone help me check what the problem in the code is? Also, when I print the $\theta$, they are exponentially increasing and the loop keeps on executing.

```
def ridge(X, y, d2):
    one = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(X.T, X) + d2 * (np.eye(8)))
    two = np.dot(X.T, y)
    theta = np.dot(one, two)
    return theta

def lasso(X, y, d2):
    theta = ridge(X, y, d2)
    k = len(theta)
    theta_ = np.zeros(k)
    A = 2 * (np.sum(X**2, axis = 0))
    while np.sum(np.abs(theta_ - theta)) > 1e-5:

        theta_ = theta.copy()

        ytile = np.tile(y, (k, 1))
        pro = np.dot(X, theta)
        protile = np.tile(pro, (k,1))
        third = np.dot(np.diag(theta), X.T)
        ########################################################
        C = np.diag(np.dot(X.T, (ytile.T - protile.T + third.T)))
        ########################################################
        for i in range(k):
            if C[i] < -d2 :
                theta[i] = ( C[i] + d2 ) / A[i]
            elif C[i] > d2 :
                theta[i] = ( C[i] - d2 ) / A[i]
            else:
                theta[i] = 0
    return theta

theta = lasso(Xtrain, ytrain, 1)
print(theta)
```